# Another [tag] ambiguity... tracking

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Not very many questions tagged [tracking](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking) at the moment, but they're basically split.

- We've got tracking as a likely synonym for [audio-recording](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording).
- And also tracking as in, "following the movement of" as it pertains to video editing software.

Perhaps tracking should be a synonym for audio-recording and [motion-tracking] or [tracking-motion]?  The two video related questions both involve the [after-effects](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-effects) tag as well.  Is tracking *only* related to that adobe product? or is it just coincidence at this point?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of renaming to [motion-tracking] and simply just re-tagging the audio questions to [audio-recording].

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the idea of getting rid of the tracking (wrt audio) tag. IMO tracking and mixing are the two main subdivisions of the audio recording process and will be helpful even if they're not used that much at the moment ( if for no other reason than the fact that they're 2 separate disciplines ... mastering being another one ) ... what about tracking-audio-recording and tracking-video-motion as a suggestion ?

Question: what about tracking on a vcr ( i know very little about video so that one is probably irrelevant or something) ?

Comment: I guess my thoughts are that the tags should be literally interpreted.  Audio-recording is not mixing.  Mixing is mixing.  Don't get me wrong, I take your point, I just think they should be literal and explicit.

Comment: Yes to 'Audio-recording is not mixing' and tags should be literally interpreted ... I suppose what I must mean is that I think all these tags are relevant audio-recording ( as the general case) and audio-mixing, audio-tracking, audio-mastering and possibly a couple of others as the subdivisions

Comment: Certainly relevant, yep I agree.  My suggestion was not to delete [tracking], but just make it a synonym.  Also, we have an [audio] tag that's used quite a bit... should help keep the subdivisions to a minimum.

Comment: I know ... I'm just not convinced that it mightn't be helpful in the future to be able to specifiy tracking and mixing somehow but I know it's important to keep subdivisions to a minimum especially if you think they might not end up getting used ... anyway it's just food for thought really

Comment: 100% :)  The back and forth is gold :)

Comment: I never heard "tracking" being related to audio *recording*. I'd call it simply **recording** or **audio-recording**.  However "tracking" meaning "following an object" is much more common to me. Just a singular opinion.